# How do I get rid of TagExtraInfo JSTL warning in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jstl

I'm working with JSTL in Eclipse, using the WTP.  I have jstl and standard.jar in my WEB-INF/lib directory, and everything works.  Eclipse is giving me this warning in my JSP:

The TagExtraInfo class for c:forEach (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI) was not found on the build path.

I have JSTL included:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

The warning is on a line that uses a c:forEach.  How can I get rid of it?
My project is targeting Tomcat v6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I accidentally double-clicked the warning, and it took me to the source, which was editable.  Then I fixed the problem myself.

Answer (score 3):

Add the standard.jar from the web-inf directory to your build path jars.

Answer (score 1):

Are the jars actually on the build path?  If so, you might try closing and reopening the project.  Otherwise that message is controllable from the Web/JSP Files/Validation preference page.